# How do I convert a whole column in a dataframe object from time to number of hours in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I am a beginner in R so please answer in the simplest way possible.
I have a dataframe (named "fintab"), which contains a column with vlues in time format (00:00:30). I would like to convert this whole column of data to numeric values of hours (0.008). I tried this code:

```
>install.packages("lubridate") 
>library("lubridate")
>hodiny <- hour(fintab$`hour:min:sec`) + minute(fintab$`hour:min:sec`) / 60 + second(fintab$`hour:min:sec`) / 3600
```

but i get this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Is there a way around this error?

Comment: Please show the str(fintab)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `hms` to create a `period` object, convert it to `numeric` to get seconds, and divide the result by 3600 to get decimal hours:

```
library(lubridate)

fintab <- '00:00:30'
as.numeric(lubridate::hms(fintab))/3600
[1] 0.008333333
```